# Infragistics Child Band Column hiding

Tags: vb.net, multiple-columns, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is it possible to display different column totals for child bands using Infragistics?

For example, say I want my grid to look like the following:

[image]

Is this possible? I've found that child bands tend to affect the entire grid, so when I hide a column of the child band (for example "Week + 2") all of those child columns are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a quote from their KB

> The Hidden property determines whether an object is visible. Hiding an object may have have effects that go beyond simply removing it from view. For example, hiding a band also hides all the rows in that band. Also, changing the Hidden property of an object affects all instances of that object. For example, a hidden column or row is hidden in all scrolling regions.

which is located here

[Ultragrid Hidden Property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~Hidden.html)

so i guess this is not possible

you could try to accomplish this with a tree though